# Convert Sql query into Realm Query

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql-server, realm

I am using Realm (version 0.87). I want to convert the sql query

`Select * from Users where 'firstname' + " "+ 'lastname' like "Ranjana Dangol".`

I tried it as

```
RealmQuery<UserEntityData> query =  realm.where(UserEntityData.class).beginGroup();
String searchQuery = "Ranjana Dangol"
String[] queries = searchQuery.split("\\s+");

for(String username : queries){
 query.equalTo(UserEntityData.FIRST_NAME, username, Case.INSENSITIVE)
 .equalTo(UserEntityData.LAST_NAME, username, Case.INSENSITIVE);
}
```

Comment: Try RealmResults<UserEntityData> r1 = realm.where(UserEntityData.class)
                             .equalTo(UserEntityData.FIRST_NAME, queries[0])
                             .equalTo(UserEntityData.LAST_NAME, queries[1])
                             .findAll();

Comment: what if the searchqQuery = "Ram Bahadur Dangol", there each field name should compare next to the word in given text. isnt it?

Comment: Yes you are right. You can use contains() function in that case. RealmResults<UserEntityData> r = realm.where(UserEntityData.class)        .equalTo(UserEntityData.FIRST_NAME, searchQuery)
.or().contains(UserEntityData.FIRST_NAME, searchQuery )
.findAll();